# error vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:833 in laravel

Tags: laravel

please help me, I'm learning and using Laravel 8.x . I don't know what is my error in this case.
...

```
vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:833
```

...

this is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        echo'admin';
    }
}
```

and this is my web.php

```
<?php
    
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/admin','AdminController@index');
```

Comment: Welcome to SO... What is the exact error shown? When does it happen eg: when trying to visit `/admin`. If you can't see the full error on screen, you can have a look at logs `/storage/logs/laravel.log`  - most recent log entry at the end of file

Comment: this is my error Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [AdminController] does not exist. I don't know what does it mean ? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Laravel 8 default namespace `App\Http\Controllers` is not registered by default in RouteServiceProvider

So you need to use FQCN for the controller in the routes file other wise you will get the container binding resolution exception as you are getting

```
<?php
   
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route; 
use App\Http\Controllers\AdminController;

Route::get('/admin', [AdminController::class, 'index']);
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens from Laravel 8, since the `App\Http\Controllers` namespace isn't registered by default. You can register it in the corresponding service provider:

```php
# app/Providers/RouteserviceProvider.php

// Uncomment this line
protected $namespace ='App\\Http\\Controllers';
```